# How to use circumflex in the field delimiter in AWK?

Tags: regex, awk

I want to use `,^` as the field delimiter, as follows:

```
echo "hello,^my,^friend" | awk -F',^' '{print $2}'
```

The above command should return `my`. But actually it returns nothing, why? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: unlike grep and sed, `^` has to be escaped to match it literally even when it is not being used as anchor

Comment: What @Sundeep is saying is, in basic regular expressions, `^` loses its special meaning if it's not the first character of a regular expression (or a subexpression in some implementations). But in extended regular expressions, there is no such restriction, `^` is an anchoring character unless it's quoted, or inside a bracket expression; and awk uses extended regular expressions by default, unlike grep and sed.

Comment: @oguzismail oh, I didn't know that it behaved differently in BRE/ERE, thanks.. I thought `^` didn't need to be escaped with grep/sed if not used as anchor for both BRE/ERE.. just checked and ERE requires escaping..

Comment: Maybe you could replace circumflexes with vertical bars and make your life easier `tr '^' '|' < yourFile | awk -F'|'`

Comment: @MarkSetchell but that misses `,` and will run into problem again with escaping `|`... perhaps you meant `tr -s ',^' '|'` ?

Comment: Sorry I missed that OP wants to use **two** characters as a delimiter... just seems to be asking for trouble IMHO I'll withdraw from the discussion as it is not a direction I would suggest at all.

Comment: @MarkSetchell - the approach you suggest is a bad practice even if the OP only wanted to use a single character as delimiter. It is possible that the data includes the pipe character (not as a separator). With your suggestion, those pipes become separators, changing their meaning. This is a very general thing, not related to `awk` or regular expressions.

Comment: @mathguy I wasn't suggesting anyone do that without consideration for, and understanding of their data... that was part of the *"maybe"* aspect. But yes, I agree in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In extended regular expressions, circumflex character's special meaning is preserved irrespective of its position in the entire expression unless it's quoted or inside a bracket expression, so you need to quote it.

```
$ echo "hello,^my,^friend" | awk -F',\\^' '{print $2}'
my
```

Compare [BRE Expression Anchoring](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_08:~:text=A%20%3Ccircumflex%3E%20(%20'%5E'%20)%20shall%20be%20an%20anchor%20when%20used%20as%20the%20first%20character%20of%20an%20entire%20BRE.) to [ERE Expression Anchoring](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_09:~:text=A%20%3Ccircumflex%3E%20(%20'%5E'%20)%20outside%20a%20bracket%20expression%20shall%20anchor%20the%20expression%20or%20subexpression%20it%20begins%20to%20the%20beginning%20of%20a%20string;%20such%20an%20expression%20or%20subexpression%20can%20match%20only%20a%20sequence%20starting%20at%20the%20first%20character%20of%20a%20string.).